# how to fix stack overflow error?

Tags: c, stack-overflow

so, i was making this program that let people know the number of contiguous subarray which sum is equal to a certain value.

i have written the code , but when i try to run this code in vcexpress 2010, it says these error

> Unhandled exception at 0x010018e7 in test 9.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.

i have tried to search for the solution in this website and other webisites, but i can't seem to find any solution which could help me fix the error in this code(they are using recursion while i'm not).

i would be really grateful if you would kindly explain what cause this error in my code, and how to fix this error. any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int n,k,a=0,t=0;
    unsigned long int i[1000000];
    int v1,v2=0,v3;

    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);

    for(v3=0;v3<n;v3++)
    {
    scanf("%d",&i[v3]);
    }

    do
    {
        for(v1=v2;v1<n;v1++)
        {
            t=i[v1]+t;
            if(t==k)
            {
                a++;
                break;
            }
        }
        t=0;
        v2++;
    }while(v2!=n);

    printf("%lu",a);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Don't try to put a million longs on the stack.

Comment: @user2357112 *don't try to use a million longs array with automatic life time. ;) static would do the job

Comment: The stack, where local variables are usually stored, is limited in size. In Windows using the Visual C compiler, the default stack size for a process is one single megabyte. Your array takes up *four* megabytes of memory (using the Visual C compiler with 32-bit `long`).

Comment: It looks like you are doing competitive coding...make the array global. It would solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either **move**

```
     unsigned long int i[1000000];
```

**outside of `main`**, thus making it a global variable (not an [automatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) one), or better yet, **use some [C dynamic heap allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)**:

```
 // inside main
 unsigned long int *i = calloc(1000000, sizeof(unsigned long int));
 if (!i) { perror("calloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

BTW, for such a pointer, I would use (for readability reasons) some other name than `i`. And near the end of `main` you'll better `free(i);`  to avoid [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Also, you could move these 2 lines after the read of `n`  and use `calloc(n, sizeof(unsigned long int))` instead of `calloc(1000000, sizeof(unsigned long int))` ; then you can handle arrays bigger than a million elements if your computer and system provides enough resources for that.

Your initial code is declaring an automatic variable which goes into the call frame of `main` on your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (which has a limited size, typically a megabyte or a few of them). On some [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) there is a way to increase the size of that call stack (in an OS-specific way). BTW each [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) has its own call stack.

As a rule of thumb, your C functions (including `main`) should avoid having call frames bigger than a few kilobytes. With the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, you could invoke it [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -g` to get useful warnings and debug information.

Read the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) wikipage. It has a nice picture worth many words. Later, find the way to query, on your operating system, the virtual address space of your process (on Linux, use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) like `cat /proc/$$/maps`  etc...). In [practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8488870/841108), your virtual address space is likely to contain many segments (perhaps a dozen, sometimes thousands). Often, the [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) or some other part of your program (or of your C standard library) uses [memory-mapped files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). The standard C heap (managed by `malloc` etc) may be organized in *several* [segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation).

If you want to understand more about virtual address space, take time to read a good book, like: [*Operating systems, three easy pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable).

If you want to query the organization of the virtual address space in some [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), you need to find an operating-system specific way to do that (on Linux, for a process of pid 1234, [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108) `/proc/1234/maps` or `/proc/self/maps` from inside the process).

Answer (score 1):

Memory is laid out much more differently than simply 4 segments(which was done long ago). The answer to the question can be generalized this way - the *global* or *dynamically allocated memory*  space is handled differently than that of *local variables* by the system, where as the memory for local variable is limited in size, memory for dynamic allocation or global variables doesn't put a lower constraint like this.

In modern system the concept of *virtual address space* is there. The process from your program gets a chunk of it. That portion of memory is now responsible for holding the required memory.

Now for dynamic allocation and so on, the process can request more memory and depending on the other processes and so on, new memory request is serviced. For dynamic or global array there is no limit process wise (of course system wise there is- *it cant have<strike>request</strike> all memory*). That's why dynamic allocation or using global variable won't cause the process to run out of it's allocated memory unlike the automatic lifetime memory that it originally had for local variables.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch.: Hope the comments are not needed. But I enjoyed interacting and the discussion. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, so I did downvote your initial answer and upvote the final version of it.

Comment: Done... and improved again my answer

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch.: Yes I am looking at how you answer...learning something ...so precise editing. I will try to follow this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can check your stack size
for example in Linux : ulimit -s (Kbytes) 
and then decide how you manipulate your code regarding that.
As a concept I would never allocate big piece of memory on the stack because unless you know exactly the depth of your function call and the stack use, it's hard to control the precised allocated memory on stack during run time

Comment: `ulimit` would change the stack limit (of the shell and future child process) at runtime. Better to get warned at compile time.